# TYPO3: felogin doesn't show any errors

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, felogin

I'm using felogin for my TYPO3 page and when I try to login and I type in a wrong e-mail, password or generally it just fails to login, I wish to show an error message. But it just doesn't show up at all. I just get redirected to my login page and that's it. Do I have to change some settings or anything for it works?

In my `setup.typoscript` I've already placed this:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
    templateFile = EXT:tjms/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/FrontendLogin.html
    # HTML-Tags ändern 
    errorHeader_stdWrap.wrap = <h1>|</h1>
    errorMessage_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="alert alert-danger">|</div>
    # Mitteilungen
    _LOCAL_LANG.de {
        ll_error_header = Achtung!
        ll_error_message = Die E-Mail existiert nicht oder ist noch nicht aktiviert! Eventuell ist auch das angegebene Passwort falsch.
    }
}
```

How do I get the `error_header` and `error_message` to display? I tried to add `###ERROR_HEADER###` to my FrontendLogin.html but it ends up just displaying literally ###ERROR_HEADER###

Any help is appreciated

Comment: FYI: Old school `###MARKERS###` aren't handled anymore in Fluid templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup some headers and messages directly in ContentElement of ***Login form***, just edit it via ***Page***/***List*** module, go to ***Messeges*** tab and set required values for:

- Welcome
- Login Success
- Login Error
- Status Display
- Logout
- Forgot Password

If you desire some more advanced layout about what happened at each step, you can use redirects also during CE editing in ***Plugin Options*** > ***Redirects*** tab and there point to an external page.

**Alternative**

You can also configure some redirects globally within ***WEB*** > ***Template*** module ***Constant Editor*** > ***Redirects*** pan.

**Note:**

Keep in mind that `TEMPLATE` cObject is currently deprecated and will be removed in TYPO3 ver.: `11.+`, therefore you shouldn't use `###MARKERS###` anymore.

Comment: sadly none of that works for me. The error message just won't show up. I just get redirected all the time to the same page without any info. I tried to remove my custom FrontEndLogin.html and use the one from core, but the same happens there. Could anything influence the display of the errors? They are nowhere: not in debug, not in the html and I'm just clueless what to do :/

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the plugin options of EXT:felogin

Comment: probably you're right, but please describe your solution little bit better.